Is it possible to create native iOS and Android libraries using .NET 8+?
I'm working on a project where I would like to create native-like libraries for both iOS and Android using pure .NET 8+ libraries (without the UI components of .NET MAUI). The goal is to compile these .NET libraries so they can be used in native iOS projects via CocoaPods and in native Android projects as a .so file. Additionally, I want to make these libraries reusable in a React Native project.
Here’s the theoretical setup:

The .NET-based project "SpecificationsProvider" (SP).
The SP project is compiled into native libraries for iOS and Android.
These libraries can be reused in any native iOS or Android projects.
Consequently, we should be able to write boilerplate code to use these libraries from React Native.

I’m looking for discussion, advice, code examples, detailed steps, or references to relevant documentation to achieve this. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
